# How does the GDK android camera example work?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk, abstraction, android-file

So I'm a little confused about what is going on towards the end of this code (inside `processPictureWhenReady()`). Before this method is called (within `onActivityResult()`) we have the image file path... So a file has already been stored. We then have the file declaration `pictureFile` using the filepath of the image (`picturePath`). Can someone explain why we have to declare a file using the same file path despite the fact that the file already exists ? Please don't just refer me back to the Google developers website as I have not found this useful.

```
private static final int TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST = 1;

private void takePicture() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String thumbnailPath = data.getStringExtra(Intents.EXTRA_THUMBNAIL_FILE_PATH);
        String picturePath = data.getStringExtra(Intents.EXTRA_PICTURE_FILE_PATH);

        processPictureWhenReady(picturePath);
        // TODO: Show the thumbnail to the user while the full picture is being
        // processed.
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void processPictureWhenReady(final String picturePath) {
    final File pictureFile = new File(picturePath);

    if (pictureFile.exists()) {
        // The picture is ready; process it.
    } else {
        // The file does not exist yet. Before starting the file observer, you
        // can update your UI to let the user know that the application is
        // waiting for the picture (for example, by displaying the thumbnail
        // image and a progress indicator).

        final File parentDirectory = pictureFile.getParentFile();
        FileObserver observer = new FileObserver(parentDirectory.getPath(),
            FileObserver.CLOSE_WRITE | FileObserver.MOVED_TO) {
            // Protect against additional pending events after CLOSE_WRITE
            // or MOVED_TO is handled.
            private boolean isFileWritten;

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
            if (!isFileWritten) {
                // For safety, make sure that the file that was created in
                // the directory is actually the one that we're expecting.
                File affectedFile = new File(parentDirectory, path);
                isFileWritten = affectedFile.equals(pictureFile);

                if (isFileWritten) {
                    stopWatching();

                    // Now that the file is ready, recursively call
                    // processPictureWhenReady again (on the UI thread).
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            processPictureWhenReady(picturePath);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    };
    observer.startWatching();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring, I presume, to this line:

```
final File pictureFile = new File(picturePath);
```

What they have done is created an instance of a `File` object from the *file path* where that image is stored. This `File` object is what they need to do some processing on the image. The `File` object is an *abstraction* of the image file in memory, **NOT** the actual physical file. As I understand it, you seem to be mistaking the two.

Comment: I followed everything you said apart from the "abstraction of the image file". Sorry but what do you mean by that exactly?

Comment: Your question is that *Can someone explain why we have to declare a file using the same file path despite the fact that the file already exists.* It seems to me that you are making the mistake of thinking that `pictureFile` is an actual *file*. It is **NOT**. `pictureFile` is just an instance of the `File` class that can be used to perform some processing & manipulation on the *actual* file. So they are not creating the same file again, they are just creating an abstract representation of it called `pictureFile`, and using that they can programmatically do some operations with that image :)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you Zygotelnit!